# Prove that $f(x) = -1-3x \pmod{2^e}$ cycles with period $2^e$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups, collatz-conjecture

This question is inspired by the Collatz-like "Binary Complement Sequences," as discussed [here](https://gladhoboexpress.blogspot.com/2022/12/binary-complement-sequences.html) and [here](https://qedscience.wordpress.com/2021/02/19/collatz-inspired-sequences/) and [here on seq-fan](http://list.seqfan.eu/pipermail/seqfan/2022-December/037014.html).

For a given exponent $e$, let $f$ be defined as $f(x) = -1-3x \pmod{2^e}$. Now calculate $f(0)$, $f^2(0) = f(f(0))$, $f^3(0)$, $f^4(0)$...

For example, when $e=3$, the sequence is $$0, 7, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 0$$ (because e.g. $f^2(0)=f(7)=-1-21\pmod{8}=2$).

Prove that this sequence is always a cyclic permutation of the integers from 0 to $2^e$.
That is, prove that $f^n(0) = 0$ iff $n \equiv 0 \pmod{2^e}$.

(I don't know that this is always true, but it *seems* to be true, and so I bet it's easy to prove for someone who knows math. :) If it's true, my next question will be whether it's possible to efficiently compute discrete logarithms in this group — like, "given $e=64$, find me the $x$ such that $f^x(0) = 42$." I know this is a well-studied hard problem for functions of the form $f(x)=px\pmod{2^e}$, but I'm not sure what effect our extra "minus 1" might have.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Credit for this answer really goes to Junekey Jeon, who had the key insight, but asked me to write it up.)

The trick is to see that iterating $f(x)=-1-3x\pmod{2^e}$ gives us exactly a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)! Using the terminology from that Wikipedia page, we have a *modulus* of $m=2^e$, a *multiplier* of $a=2^e-3$, an *increment* of $c=2^e-1$, and a *seed* of $X_0=0$.

By the Hull–Dobell Theorem, an LCG with $c\neq 0$ will have period $m$ if and only if all three of these conditions hold:

- $m$ and $c$ are relatively prime (yes: $c$ is odd),
- $a\equiv 1$ mod $p$ whenever $p$ is a prime factor of $m$ (yes: the only such $p$ is 2, and $a\equiv 1$ mod 2),
- $a\equiv 1$ mod 4 whenever 4 divides $m$ (yes: $2^e-3\equiv 1$ mod 4 whenever $2^e\equiv 0$ mod 4).

So, all three conditions hold, and so this LCG does have period $m=2^e$.

Answer (score 0):

It is true by the definition of the modulo operation,
every sequence $ a \bmod b $  is cyclic with period $ b $, because for $ a \in [\,0, b ]\, $, $ a \bmod b = a $ .
For $ a \notin [\,0, b )\, $, $ a \bmod b \equiv a + kb \bmod b $, where $ k $ is any integer.

So, from that, $ a \equiv a + b \equiv a + 2b \equiv \cdots $

$ f(x) = -1-3x $ is a linear function, which means the sequence created by inputting integers into this function creates a linear sequence.
Therefore, applying a scaling factor $ s $, we can make it equal to $ f(x) = x + C $

In this case, $ s = - \frac{1}{3} $, which gives $ sf(x) = x + \frac{1}{3} $

From there we have a direct relation between $ f(x) $ and $ a $, becasue $ (sa \bmod b) = s(a \bmod b) $.

In other words, every linear sequence is cyclic with the period being at most whatever number you write on the right of the modulo function.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, does it? I mean, of course any sequence at all, over a finite set of elements, must cycle; but how do you distinguish a sequence like f(x)=-3x-1 (which seems-to-have period 2^e) from a sequence like f(x)=-3x (where f(0)=0 so it always has period 1), from f(x)=-3x-2 (where all the terms are even so it definitely doesn't have period 2^e), and so on? Saying "its cycle has period _at most_ 2^e" is obvious.

Comment: If it is obvious then I don't really get what the question is, if the period is at most 2^e, then does that not answer your question? The period may be smaller, yes, but if it is smaller, such as 2^(e-1), then we can extend it to make a "double period" if I may say that of 2^e. I also should've said, that the period must divide 2^e, that might help. Also, f(x)=-3x+C has the same period length for every C.

Comment: If the period is smaller than 2^e, then (1) the period is NOT EQUAL to 2^e, and (2) the resulting permutation is not cyclic. Yes, it is obvious that the period must divide 2^e; that doesn't help to prove that the period must EQUAL 2^e. Also, f(x)=-3x+C obviously does NOT have the same period length for every C; C=0 gives period 1, and C=2 has period at most 2^{e-1}.

Comment: A sequence [a(n) = 0 for even, 1 for odd] is periodic mod 2, but also mod 4, is it not?